How can I click on Tuesday April 15 2025 button?

I am using Eclipse/Java with Selenium. I'm unable to locate and click the April 15st 2025 button.
Code
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'eoY5cb') and text()='Tuesday, April 15, 2025, return date.']')]")).sendKeys("Tuesday, April 15, 2025");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class*='eoY5cb']")).click();


We can't help without the HTML you are using... ideally the URL. You also need to clarify the scenario... what are you trying to validate? The initial click to set the date or are you wanting to set the date to April 15 and then validate that date is set elsewhere or the page or ???

Thanks for the reply. I want to find April 15th and click on it...

Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea. Edit your question and add the HTML as text, properly formatted.

Validate means to verify something... you perform some action and then validate that it was successful. What you mean to say is you can't find or locate and click the button. I've updated your question.

A CSS selector should work fine.
div[aria-label='Tuesday, April 15, 2025']

The full code to click it with a wait would be,
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div[aria-label='Tuesday, April 15, 2025']"))).click();


It works; thanks
